# Is there a way provided by nextjs 13 to protect routes?

Tags: javascript, next.js, routes

I have following pages **/about, /user, /user/[id]**. Since I cannot access **req.page** which gives us **slug** i.e. (/user/[id]), I couldn't apply logic to redirect requests made by unauthenticated users. So, my question is there any specific way that **nextjs 13** provides to protect routes.

I tried the `next-shield` which is package to handle this problem. But that gives us flashy content.

Comment: I would take a look at next middleware

Answer (score 0):

`import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'` Can solve this problem in SSR

Suppose you have a url/route for creating new blog post called `/new-post` and you want to protect that url for a non-auth user and redirect them to other pages.

This is what you want to do in that case

```
const newPost = async () => {
  const loginStatus = await getLoginStatus() // get the login status
  if (!loginStatus.isLoggedIn) {
    redirect('/') // Redirect them to other pages that can access by any non-auth user
  }
  return (
    <div>
      /* Create new post page content here */
    </div>
  )
}
export default newPost
```

And as all components are run on the server in nextjs 13 this will be ready on the server.

[Refer to docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect)